# How to calculate mix-blend-mode:difference white output

Tags: html, css, mix-blend-mode

Given any color that is not the basic ones (combinations of 255 and 0), how can I get the input color value to which mix-blend-mode:difference will output white?

When trying to create an effect like this:
[shape and tet overlaping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIwiP.png)
I've come across the problem of how to get a white output from the mix-blend-mode:difference property. Since I don't use a basic color, the RGB invert color doesn't generate the desired output. Am I missing something?

Here is a [www3school example link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.php?filename=trycss_mix-blend-mode) in which you can play around and a screenshot of the current behavior:
[Using RGB color and its opposite doesn't output white in mix-blend-mode:difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9Cgz.png)

I've edited it so you can see what I'm talking about (copy&paste to use it):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
:root {
    --color: rgb(226,2,58);
    --invert-color: rgb(29,253,197);
}

.container {
  background-color: rgb(226,2,58);
  padding: 15px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 16px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

.container .same {
  background-color: var(--color);
}

.container .invert {
  background-color: var(--invert-color);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>The mix-blend-mode Property</h2>
<p>The mix-blend-mode property specifies how an element's content should blend with its background:</p>

<div class="container">
  <div class="same"></div>
  <div class="invert"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suspect you can’t do this just using difference.

Comment: And any alternative other than difference? I also tried applying an invert filter but the order of the operations doesn't seem to work.